# how to get week starts from Saturday and ends with Friday sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query where the condition is Week starts from Saturday and ends with Friday SQL query along with last deposit date of that week should be used in the first column AS [Weekending] as preview for every week 
I have tried the following

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATEADD(DD, 7 - CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, PostDate), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1), PostDate) AS WeekEndDate
FROM 
    [MasterReport]
WHERE
    PostDate BETWEEN '12/30/2017' AND '07/1/2018'
```

The output which I am currently getting:

[image: output]

But the desired output should be like this:

[image: finaloutput]

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems that your table `TransactionMasterReport` might not have any record with `PostDate` value between `2018-13-01` and `2018-19-01`.

Comment: no there is data for the particular dates. i tried another query:Select  distinct LastFriday = dateadd(dd,(datediff(dd,-53686,PostDate)/7)*7,-53686) from [TransactionMasterReport]
  where PostDate between '01/2/2018' and '07/1/2018'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to sort your result. Try query below.

```
SELECT distinct
DATEADD(DD,7-CHOOSE(DATEPART(dw, PostDate), 2,3,4,5,6,7,1),PostDate) AS WeekEndDate
from [TransactionMasterReport]
where PostDate between '12/30/2017' and '07/1/2018'
order by WeekEndDate
```